# Chat messages should use consistent icon in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

It'd be nice if the chat notifications in the feed used the default Stack Exchange icon like the ones in the inbox do*:

[image: chat notification in inbox]
[image: chat notification in feed, sans icon]

Since items in the feed are grouped so that multiple items from the same site [only show that site's icon once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QlPw.png), the site icon helps delimit grouped items a bit less subtlely than the grey divider lines, and chat replies' lack of one causes them to sort of blend in to the previous group.

<sub>*Ideally it'd use the icon of the site the room was associated with, but I don't think that information is readily available</sub>

Comment: Have you seen this behavior recently?  It could have been that back in February we didn't have the icons set up for all the inbox item types, and the default icon where one is missing is the SE logo.

Comment: They're consistently blank in both places now, but I'd rather they had *some* icon for the reasons mentioned above.