# Inconsistency with icons for chat replies in the iOS app

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, ios-app

I already know about the [lack of icon for chat replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220793/339911) in the iOS app. Moreover I have a [dup post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287796/339911) about it. But now I noticed that chat replies from MSE chat domain do **have icons**:

Feed:

> [image: feed]

Inbox:

> [image: inbox]

As you can see, replies from "Stack Overflow на русском" don't contain an icon, but replies from "Meta StackExchange" chat have it.

Is it a first step of previously noticed bug fix :) or new another bug?

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)